# Selecting features with attachments using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attachments

I have an attachment enabled feature class that has [photos attached to points](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/21/using-attachments-to-manage-associated-feature-content/). However while any feature in the layer *might* have a photo, only 10-15% actually *do*.

How can I narrow in on just those?

The only methods I've discovered rely on one by one interrogation ([identify popup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000) windows or [attribute table while editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000p000000)), which is not at all interesting to me in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the **[Enabling Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m90000000r000000)** help page it says:

> When you enable attachments, ArcGIS creates a new table to contain the
>   attachment files and a new relationship class to relate the features
>   to the attached files.

Consequently, you are able to use that relationship class to determine which features are present, and they will be only those with attachments.

To select your features with attachments use the instructions on the **[Exploring the related objects of an object in a table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004t0000000w000000)** help page.  My instructions here are paraphrased from those.

1. Right-click on the feature class and use **Joins & Relates | Relate** to relate using the **OBJECTID** to the ***_ATTACH** table's **ATTACHMENTID**
2. Use the **List By Source** view of the **Table of Contents** to open the ***_ATTACH** table that represents the attachments.
3. **Select All** the rows (attachments).
4. Click **Options > Related Tables**, then click the path label for the relationship.  A new table dialog box opens for the attribute table of the feature class with attachments enabled, and all features with an attachment should be found selected there.

I just tested this at **ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop** and it worked!  I used a Standard license but you are not trying to modify a relationship class, just view using one, so a Basic license should be fine to use.

Comment: Huh; doesn't work for me. Under "Related Tables" it says "None". Though if I use ArcCatalog and explore the file-gdb it has `Points_of_interest` (point feature class), `Points_of_interest_ATTACH` (table), `Points_of_interest_ATTACHREL` (relationship class) listed. Using *Identify* on a point with known with attachments does show them. Explicitly adding the \*_ATTACH to the table of contents doesn't change anything. If I manually create an *additional* relationship between FC and *_ATTACH then the recipe works. So I can get what I want eventually, but the process is broken.

Comment: @mattwilkie You were right, in my testing I had done an extra step during experimentation and had overlooked that it was critical to this workflow.  I have added it as step 1 now.

Comment: Accepted as correct because it does answer the question asked, though why a person should have to define a soft related table link when a hard relationship class link already exists is beyond me. Still some more work to be done before feature level attachments are a first class citizen I guess. :-/

Comment: In ArcMap 10.5 the default field name for the relationship is not the **ATTACHMENTID**, but however it is the **REL_OBJECTID**.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the feature class has an attribute containing the path to the photo it is linked to... If that is the case, an easy way would be to use the "Select by Attribute" method or apply a filter method, where:

```sql
show everything where attribute is not NULL
```

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect because "the feature class [does not have] an attribute containing the path to the photo it is linked to".  This is because there is potentially a many-to-many relationship between features and attachments (photos).  Where the photos are stored is known directly to the attachment table and to the feature class only via the relationship class.

Comment: I see... can't you use that relationship class with the feature class and then apply the filter?

Comment: If you can, it is not a technique that I know, so feel free to try and, if successful, then edit your Answer to revise it with the steps involved.